# how to manage different python versions on a computer

Tags: python, pip, archlinux

I recently moved my os from debian7 to archlinux. On debian 7, the default python version is python2.7 but on archlinux the default is python3.4.

I once wrote a spider program using beautifulsoup4 on my debian7 but now I want to run this program on archlinux.

I use `sudo pacman -S python-pip`to install pip and then use `sudo pip install beautifulsoup4`. But this time this package goes into `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/`.

I know I can download bs4 to my spider's directory and run it with python2, but I just want to know how do you install packages using `pip`since you have 2 python version installed. And btw if I change the default python link to python2*, will it break my system?

Comment: download the get-pip.py https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py and run it with python2.7 then use pip2 to install packages for  python2.7

Comment: What the heck is a "spider program"? Why do you have a "spider directory" and what's the link with the python version you have installed?

Comment: note that `pip install --user beautifulsoup4` is slightly less invasive than using `sudo`.  also note that arch has `python-beautifulsoup4` and `python2-beautifulsoup4` packages already  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `python2-pip` and `pip2` or `pip2.7`.

In arch linux all of the python 3 packages have no version number and all the python 2 packages have a `2`.  The commands are the same way.

To select what version a script uses use the version number in the hashbang.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2
```

or

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
```

I'm not sure if debian has a `python2` link but they can easily be created on systems where `/usr/bin/python` is `python2.7`.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python{2,2.7}
```

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python{2,2.7} will this crash my system? since the default python links to python3.4.

Comment: That was meant to be run on debian where `python` is `python2.7`.  Please never run that if `python` is not `python2.7`

Answer (score 0):

*"on archlinux the default is python3.4"* - wow, this is ambitious.

The [archlinux wiki on Python](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/python) provides a lot of tips.  You should install `python2-pip` to make sure that pip is installed for the right version.

Comment: I've never heard of python2-pip before, I will try this. Is it that because the default python is python3, so the default pip downloads python3 packges?

Answer (score 0):

Archlinux usually provides packages prefixed with `python-` for Python 3.x and `python2-` for Python 2.x. You can also use [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html) to manage local Python environments, which means you can have a Python2 project and a Python3 project without conflicts between them.

Comment: Virtualenv is completely unnecessary for this probem as 2 and 3 can happily live side-by-side and Arch has them both packaged for you.

Comment: I know what you means, but even if I use <code>virtualenv</code>I have to use pip2 to install packages. I hate this version difference.